# rhomobile and oauth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, foursquare, rhodes, rhomobile

Based on this stackoverflow question [foursquare oauth2 for IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486370/foursquare-oauth2-for-ios)

I need to send user from my app to foursquare.  Get permission and redirect to my web server.  I get the access token, but how do I redirect to a view?

In my rhomobile controller I have

```
def fsq_login
  WebView.navigate('https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate?client_id=MY CLIENT_IT&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://lvh.me:3000/fsq_req')
end
```

Once I have the access_token, how can I get my webserver to trigger a rhomobile view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to set your redirect uri to point back to your Rhodes application using the following:

http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/device-caps#run-rhodes-application-from-browser

Comment: Tried that but doesn't launch app.  I have `android: BundleURLScheme: myapp` and `iphone: BundleIdentifier: com.rhomobile.myapp, BundleURLScheme: myapp` w/o comma, but nothing.  have a test link of `<a href="myapp:/app/User/show>test</a> but this doesn't work either.  Been at this for 2 days now and don't know where i'm going wrong.

Comment: take it back.  Changed callback url to 127.0.0.1 and it worked.  Thanks.